# MongoDB as pure in-memory DB on Windows?

Tags: windows, mongodb, redis

I recently read this interesting article:
[How to use MongoDb as a pure in-memory DB (Redis style)](http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/49304254688/how-to-use-mongodb-as-a-pure-in-memory-db-redis-style)

In my scenario I will only have access to a windows machine, hence the question if it would be possible to do the same on Windows?

Why MongoDB instead of Redis? I was hoping to leverage geospatial indices.

The actual data would be rebuilt easily upon restart of MongoDB as it would only be about 0.5 GB of data.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/217743

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like the tutorial told you.
Create a [Ram Disk](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/create-10-gbs-ram-disk-windows/)